# Carousel Navigation Thumbnails

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I notice that Twitter Bootstrap has very little customisation modes.  For example I want to create a carousel where I have links that are the navigation, to which you can jump to the slide you want to.

Is this even possible with the standard and I've missed it?

UPDATE MY CODE:

```
<section id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ul class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <!-- @placeholder 1000x400 Slide 1 -->
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- @placeholder 1000x400 Slide 2 -->
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- @placeholder 1000x400 Slide 3 -->
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <!-- @placeholder 1000x400 Slide 4 -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </section>
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

Comment: Yes of course.  My opening words mention I have noticed Twitter Bootstrap and its very little modes of customisation.

Comment: Yes, but there are links on there...no? The little circles.  Also bootstrap has plenty of customization available.  You can do whatever you want if you define your own CSS

Comment: Oh yeah, hmm, I never noticed that it was going to the specific slide.

Comment: Here's an example that may help -- links on the bottom http://www.bootply.com/113737

Comment: Yeah I have the same links, doesn't work for me.

Comment: It slides automatically ok, but the links just don't work.

Comment: Right I've got 1.9.1 jQuery, got the updated bootstrap.  no warnings, yet it just doesn't work.  The links don't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

The little circles provide links to an individual slide.

Comment: Yeah I did that,  didn't work.

See here -> http://sportspages.getforge.io/templates/pages/home

Comment: Well it works on the demo :) Double check all of your classes etc. against the demo.  Not sure what else to tell you.

Comment: Anyone able to shed some light?